# How do I downgrade openssl?

Tags: centos, ssh, openssl

I am trying to install the StGeorge payment gateway api on my CewntOS VPS. But when I tried running

```
php test.php
```

I get error: `error while opening file libwebpayclient.so`

So I tried: `ldd libwebpayclient.so`

Which showed that `libssl.so.6` and `libcrypto.so.6` are **not found**. So my guess was openssl was not installed, but when I tried `yum install openssl`, I find that the latest openssl-1.0.0 is installed on the server.   So I am guessing i need to downgrade it to openssl-0.9.8e which has the libcrypto.so.6 files....but I don't know how to downgrade and whether I should even downgrade at all? What are your suggestions to this problem?

And if I do have to downgrade, please tell me the exact steps to do so, because I am not very familiar with command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `openssl098e` package in CentOS 6 which you should be able to install with `yum`:

```
yum install openssl098e
```

Comment: It is also possible to specify a different install root with RPM (e.g.  rpm --root /usr/local/ openssl098e). That being the case if you only need the libraries for one app/module, you can install them in a different root and just set LD_CONFIG_PATH to point at them for the one app. (make sure you set the dir where the downgraded one is before everything else in LD_CONFIG_PATH)